# Simple JAVA package (possibly code) for a grid visualization

Tags: java, grid, visualization

I am going to start a project on Markov Decision Processes and am starting up a basic framework to work in. The first thing I want to set up is a grid of n by n, with cells which are empty or occupied  by some class of agents (lets say a monkey, banana and palm tree). I want to be able to visualize this with JAVA. But am actually hoping that I will not have to write the code from scratch, i.e. the visualization part.

So, a grid of n by n, with (possible) some word, picture or number in each cell. Any ideas on existing packages?

Comment: This is not a site for library recommendations. If you need a graphical interface, you could use Swing, use something such as `GridLayout`, then have a panel for each gridspace

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a JTable

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Setting the appropiate TableCellRenderer you can display each cell the way you like.
The problem is that you have to write some code.